# Python xlrd returns a no attribute error

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I'm trying to get a list of list with the values of certain cells within my xlsx worksheet but when I run it, it says there is no attribute called value. when I run the code without the ".value" method it will return a list of lists formatted the way I want but they all have the value None.

```
import xlrd

gmails = "/home/ro/Downloads/100 Gmail (1).xlsx"

def open_worksheet(file_path):
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file_path)
    ws = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
    return ws

def get_cell(worksheet, row, col):
    cell = worksheet.cell(row, col)


def get_email_list(worksheet):
    email_list = []
    first_gmail = [1, 3]
    first_password = [1, 3]
    first_recovery_gmail = [1, 5]
    for row in range(1, worksheet.nrows):
        gmail = get_cell(worksheet, first_gmail[0], first_gmail[1])
        password = get_cell(worksheet, first_password[0], first_password[1])
        recovery = get_cell(worksheet, first_recovery_gmail[0], first_recovery_gmail[1])

        first_gmail[0] += 1
        first_password[0] += 1
        first_recovery_gmail[0] += 1

        email_list.append([gmail.value, password.value, recovery.value])
    return email_list

print get_email_list(open_worksheet(gmails))
```

My Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitter.py", line 36, in <module>
    print get_email_list(open_worksheet(gmails))
  File "twitter.py", line 33, in get_email_list
    email_list.append([gmail.value, password.value, recovery.value])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Comment: you have no `return` statement in your `get_cell` function which means `gmail,password,recover` are all getting set to `NoneType` (a no return function will return `NoneType` implicitly. `return cell` maybe?

Comment: @rnar Ah yes, thankyou. it was a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_cell(worksheet, row, col):
    cell = worksheet.cell(row, col)
```

needs to be:

```
def get_cell(worksheet, row, col):
    return worksheet.cell(row, col)
```